# Get Linux to access internet through a router in a different subnet

Tags: linux, networking, proxmox

I have a bit of an odd setup. I have a proxmox cluster running on my desk, all of the computers sproxmox VMs as well. I know it isn't a DNS issue, because I can't even ping the DNS addresses. Does anyone know why Linux is having issues connecting to the internet?

Just to make sure. I have the proxmox network on the 192.168.2.0 subnet, 192.168.0.0 is my home network. My PC has a NIC connected to each. One NIC is wireless with IP of 192.168.0.52, the other is wired with the IP of 192.168.2.50. I have routes setup on my PC to connect between the two NICs

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My Linux VMs are will not connect to the internet. The edge router is in the subnet 192.168.0.0 I have my PC setup with RRAS to route traffic from the 192.168.2.0 subnet to the 192.168.0.0 subnet. Does anyone know why the Linux VMs cannot communicate to the internet?